# Install Linux on android phone

Tags: grub2, system-installation, ubuntu-for-android

Post for Suggestion:

scenery: I want to install ubuntu on android phone. not running ubuntu beside android. Remove android from boot and use grub to boot the phone.

Question: Is it possible?

If possible then how?

Comment: I wanted to mean that there will be no android, pure linux i.e. Ubuntu will be installed

Comment: Short answer is, you cannot. Android devices have their own bootloaders (and not all use the same bootloader), and generally have binary blob drivers that only work with a specific kernel version. Custom images for the OS must be built specifically for each device.